# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf Genera el documento en blanco

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Acabo de instalar el paquete `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf`según lo indica el repositorio de github, y me genera un PDF en blanco, no hay datos. Tengo los siguientes archivos:

Controller:

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

public function download()
{
    $badges = Badge::groupBy('code')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(25);
    $total_parcial = $badges->sum('amount');
    $total = Badge::sum('amount'); 

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('badges.pdf', compact('badges', 'total', 'total_parcial'));

    return $pdf->download('reporte.pdf');
}
```

Vista:

```
@section('content')
<div class="row py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12 mx-auto">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body table-responsive">

                @if ($badges->isEmpty())

                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h5>No se encontraron registros de divisas</h5>
                    </div>

                @else

                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Fecha</th>
                                <th>No. de cobro</th>
                                <th>Total unitario</th>
                                <th>Divisa</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($badges as $badge)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ $badge->created_at->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ ucwords($badge->payment_number) }}</td>
                                    <td>${{ $badge->total }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ $badge->currency }}</td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                         <div class="col-12">
                                            <strong>Total Parcial: </strong>${{ $total_parcial }} <br>
                                            <strong>Total: </strong>${{ $total }}
                                         </div>   
                                    </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Ruta:

```
Route::get('badges/download', 'BadgeController@download')->name('badges.download')->middleware('permission:badges.download');
```

Comment: Le agregaste `extends('layout')` en la parte superior de tu vista?

Comment: Sí, pero daba problemas con las fuentes en el `CSS` pero de necesitarlo debo pasar las fuentes al directorio `storage` o usar `CDNs`, lo de la página en blanco se solucionó quitanto `@section` y `@endsection` no sé los motivos aún.